# Can't load Phoenix JDBC driver for Storm's JdbcInsertBolt

Tags: java, hbase, apache-storm, apache-phoenix

During initialization of Apache's Storm `JdbcInsertBolt` I get an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  Cannot cast org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver to javax.sql.DataSource
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:90)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:292)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:84)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:102)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
at org.apache.storm.jdbc.common.HikariCPConnectionProvider.prepare(HikariCPConnectionProvider.java:53)
at org.apache.storm.jdbc.mapper.SimpleJdbcMapper.<init>(SimpleJdbcMapper.java:43)
```

from the underlying `HikariCPConnectionProvider`. Whats wrong?

I am following http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.2/storm-jdbc.html, here is what I am doing based on that:

I like to write data from a Apache Storm topology to a HBase table via Phoenix. For that I downloaded the driver-file (`phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.3003-25-client.jar`) from my cluster-Server and added it to my local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file 
  -Dfile=lib\phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.3003-25-client.jar 
  -DgroupId=org.apache.phoenix 
  -DartifactId=phoenix-jdbc -Dversion=4.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

After that I updated my `.pom`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now add Storm's JDBC-Bolt:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I am set-up to use the bolt. First: Setup Connection-Provider:

```
Map hikariConfigMap = new HashMap();
hikariConfigMap.put("dataSourceClassName", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
hikariConfigMap.put("dataSource.url", "<zookeeperQuorumURI>:2181:/hbase-unsecure");
this.connectionProvider = new HikariCPConnectionProvider(hikariConfigMap);
```

Now initialize the tuple-values-to-db-columns-mapper

```
this.simpleJdbcMapper = new SimpleJdbcMapper(this.tablename, connectionProvider);
```

During this the error mentioned above happens.

Just for completeness: The `JdbcInsertBolt` gets created like this:

```
new JdbcInsertBolt(this.connectionProvider, this.simpleJdbcMapper)
        .withTableName(this.tablename)
        .withQueryTimeoutSecs(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set :

*driverClassName* -> org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver. The current code seems to have set the dataSourceClassName which is different i guess

Refering  [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)